# Messagesight adds data the message when forwarding to MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have setup a topic to MQ messaging. The setup is done like in the documentation "MQ Connectivity scenario 2: Fan in per device notification" it appears as though Messagesight adds data the the message when it arrives at MQ destination. (possibly JMS header data). Is there something that has to be setup either on messagesight or MQ manager to remove the data and only leave the message?

Comment: The data added to the message will most likely be JMS header data, specifically related to the fact that these are publications (e.g. topic information). If that's the case then MQ gives you a way to strip this type of information from messages by setting the PROPCTL attribute of a queue to NONE.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm?lang=en

Comment: Brilliant answer Dave - suggest you could make it into an answer (look down a bit) to keep it for posterity and allow us users to upvote it.